# Duplicating an element of a multi-dimensional Array using operators

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, operators

I have a code that goes like this:

```
array = [['x', 3], ['y', 3]*2]
print(array)
```

**Output:**

```
>> [['x', 3], ['y', 3, 'y', 3]]
```

However, the **result** that I want to get is: `[['x', 3], ['y', 3], ['y', 3]]`

My question is, how do you duplicate a certain element of a multi-dimensional array using **operators**?

Comment: `array = [['x', 3], *[['y', 3]]*2]`; NB: `array[1]` and `array[2]` are same objects, mutating either of them in-place changes would be reflected in both of them. [Read about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: If you want two different objects `array = [['x', 3], *[['y', 3] for _ in range(2)]]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way for Operators But,
You can Use `copy()` Check the [**Docs**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy)

Copy the element you want then add it to the array

```py
array = [['x', 3], ['y', 3]]
copy = array[1].copy()
array.append(copy)
```

You can create a new class type and customize the Operators functionality for it